# Search,filter database form make more secure

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have following code,and my problem is how to make it more safety to SQL injection.
Can you tell me what's wrong am i doing wrong and correct my code if that's possible??
How can i make it more secure to SQL injection,how can i sanitize it or other method that prevents SQL injection.
i don't know how can i do it.

thank you for help

in my index.html

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="checkout"></p>
<select name="search" >
<option value="" disabled selected>To where</option>
<option value="hative">hative</option>
<option value="waai">waai</option>
<option value="pantai">pantai</option>
<option value="gunung">gunung</option>
<option value="passo">passo</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and index.php (for show all results)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var brand = get_filter('brand');
           var brands = get_filter('brands');
        //var ram = get_filter('ram');
        //var storage = get_filter('storage');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            //data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price},
            data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, brand:brand,brands:brands},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:0,
        max:600,
        values:[0, 600],
        step:50,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

And last is fetch_data.php

```
include('database_connection.php');
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM hotels  WHERE product_status = '1'
 ";
 if(isset($_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_price"]))
 {
  $query .= "
   AND product_price BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_price"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_price"]."'  ";
 }
if(isset($_POST["brand"]))
 {   
   $brand_filter = implode("','", $_POST["brand"]);
  $query .= "  AND product_price BETWEEN '100' AND '130' ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["brands"]))
 {   
   $brand_filter = implode("','", $_POST["brands"]);
  $query .= "  AND product_price BETWEEN '400' AND '600' ";
 }
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
 $output = '';
 if($total_row > 0)
 {
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
     $output .= '
   
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12">
        <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px; height:250px;">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">     
                <a href="'. $row['hotel_page'] .'"><img src="image/'. $row['hotel_image'] .'" width="100%" height="200px" alt="" class="img-responsive" ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xl-6">
             ' . $rating_element . '
            <p align="center"><strong><a href="'. $row['hotel_page'] .'">'. $row['hotel_name'] .'</a></strong></p>
                <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="text-danger" >'. $row['product_price'] .'</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

   </div>
   ';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
 }
 echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Andrew, the edit I have done for your question was meant to improve its grammar. Why did you reject it?

Comment: im sorry,just clicked wrong..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called parameterized query and [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) has full support for that. If you are lucky, it's already enabled in your PHP. If not, then you will need to enable it (look into php.ini and possibly install the necessary extention).

Example for connection:

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

Taken from https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Query examples:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status=?');
$stmt->execute([$email, $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
// or
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND status=:status');
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email, 'status' => $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

So, instead of putting a variable into a string that represents the query and allowing whatever malicious code in that parameter might be to be executed, instead of that you can use parameterized query and let PDO do the heavylifting for you. The only thing you will need to apply is to look through all your code, convert hard-coded values into parameters in the queries and modify your code in order to use PDO and pass the parameters, of course.

Comment: How can i change my code to parameterized query and PDO ?

Comment: @andrewpuni Please take a look at my answer. It contains examples of parameterized queries. The parameters can be added as a ? sign or as :parametername. Please reread the answer carefully. For example you have `AND product_price BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_price"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_price"]."'  "` where you pass `$_POST["minimum_price"]` and `$_POST["maximum_price"]` as they are, which is unsafe. Instead try to do something like `AND product_price BETWEEN ? AND ?  "` or ``AND product_price BETWEEN :minimum_price AND :maximum_price  "``

Comment: @andrewpuni and you need to define the values, see the array passed to the `execute` method that are definining what values should PDO sanitize. Now, please try with simpler examples before you do it on your longer query. You will see that the approach works and your future self will thank you if you do so.

Comment: I think i get it now..i just have last question,,is it enough for make it secure if i just correct all my queries by parameterize them? is it will be safe enough? thank you

Comment: @andrewpuni mostly yes. In reality, no. SQL injection is still possible in some cases even if the input is sanitized. For example, if you have a numeric input and your query does a check like where foo = <somenumber>, then if the user passes `12; delete from users;` as the number, then SQL Injection is still possible. But that's a different problem. In short: PDO does a good job in sanitizing the input, but you still need to do some validations on non-numeric inputs.

Comment: @andrewpuni a good way to circumvent the issue is to put quotes around non-numeric input values as well, like where yournumber = '345', that paired with sanitation would help a resolving SQL injection. But, even then there is a further way to inject SQL.

Comment: @andrewpuni if your tables contain SQL code, then you will need to treat the user input for those fields as if it was SQL code and perform further validations on it. However, this does not apply to you if there is no SQL code stored in your database.

Comment: That does it..i get your point and thank you for great explanation .i'll follow your advices and add some validation to non-numeric inputs

Comment: @andrewpuni this mostly covers SQL Injection as a topic, but there are other possible injections, like HTML injection, XML injection, CSS injection, Templating injection etc. Security is a very complex topic and it would be a too big task from your current perspective to cover everything. I suggest that you should learn step-by-step, first sanitize your queries with PDO, then analyze your database further to see whether there are further possible problems, see how the data is used and what can be injected where.

Comment: @andrewpuni happy to help!

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate question and this particular subject is covered extensively in other threads.